# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

The error I get is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory
```

Relevant code -

```
public void delete(int position) {
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); //this is null
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM LOGIN WHERE _ID=1;");
db.close();
}
```

This is code in DBHelper.class. Data addition and select works but deletion only cause an error. what is wrong here?

All of DBHelper code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            String DROP_SQL = "drop table if exists LOGIN";
            db.execSQL(DROP_SQL);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in DROP_SQL", ex);
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(" CREATE TABLE LOGIN ( ");
        sb.append(" _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
        sb.append(" ID TEXT, ");
        sb.append(" PW TEXT ) ");
        try {
            db.execSQL(sb.toString());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in CREATE_SQL", ex);
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.make, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.upgrade, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void addLogin(Login login) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(" INSERT INTO LOGIN ( ");
        sb.append(" ID, PW ) ");
        sb.append(" VALUES ( ?, ? ) ");
        if(login.getId().equals("") || login.getPw().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.nodata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            db.execSQL(sb.toString(),
                    new Object[]{
                            login.getId(),
                            login.getPw(),
                    });;
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.insert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); //this is null
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM LOGIN WHERE _ID=1;");
        db.close();
        //????
          //db.execSQL("DELETE FROM LOGIN WHERE _ID=" + position + ";");
        //?? ???


    }


    public List getAllData() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(" SELECT _ID, ID, PW FROM LOGIN ");
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
        List list = new ArrayList();
        Login login = null;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            login = new Login();
            login.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
            login.setId(cursor.getString(1));
            login.setPw(cursor.getString(2));
            list.add(login);
        }

        return list;

    }

}
```

full error

08-01 11:14:34.094 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
08-01 11:14:34.134 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
08-01 11:24:33.866 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-01 11:24:33.916 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{a6dc7d0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@5f1945b {com.yonoo.naverloginhelper/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper.DBActivity}} show : true
08-01 11:24:33.916 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-01 11:24:33.916 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-01 11:24:39.086 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
08-01 13:36:26.303 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1000) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1000) or=1
08-01 13:36:26.373 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@5f1945b time:11500752
08-01 13:36:27.323 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
08-01 13:36:27.463 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
08-01 13:36:27.963 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
08-01 13:36:28.063 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
08-01 13:36:28.073 23589-23589/com.yonoo.naverloginhelper D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:283)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                at com.yonoo.naverloginhelper.DBHelper.delete(DBHelper.java:71)
                                                                                at com.yonoo.naverloginhelper.DBActivity.DeleteList(DBActivity.java:70)
                                                                                at com.yonoo.naverloginhelper.LoginListAdapter$1.onClick(LoginListAdapter.java:76)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Show the full stacktrace, please

Comment: added stacktrace

Comment: I would check the rest of the stacktrace for errors. The database probably didn't get created because of the  onCreate exceptions

Comment: Actually, the duplicate is accurate, the Context is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app permissions. Manifest and runtime.

Where you set your database name and versions?

You can create your constructor like this. And your db name and version is always the same.

```
// Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = MyDatabase.db;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
}
```